# Strange polygons and lines in QGIS project that have no data or layers attached to them

Tags: qgis

I have a strange problem where two polygons and a line in my project have no data layers associated. In the screenshot below I have toggled off all of my layers and these shapes still appear.

I am running QGIS 3.30.2.

Do you have any suggestions on what to try?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be annotations, which you can select/delete with the `Modify Annotations` tool.

While you can add more annotation layers, the main one doesn't appear in the layer list.

[image]